# Shouldn't this function return the list back with all elements in it?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defun r (list)
  (let ((o ()))
    (dolist (x list o)
      (cons o x))))

(r (list 1 2 3))
```

It does not. it returns `nil`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(dolist (x list o)...`? Seems like a typo.

Comment: Also, you probably mean `(setf o (cons o x))`. Is the goal to reverse the list?

Comment: It seems like it should be `(dolist (x list)...`

Comment: @Eelvex: (dolist (x list o) ...) is valid. It returns the value of o.

Comment: @Rainer: yes it is... but what's the point of return `o` (which is `nil`) here?

Comment: @Eelvex: the point is that he just needs to change o, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change *o* somewhere. PUSH for example has the desired side-effect. CONS does not.

```
(defun r (list)
  (let ((o ()))
    (dolist (x list o)
      (push x o))))

> (r (list 1 2 3))
(3 2 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `dolist` block returns the final value of variable `o`.  Your variable `o` is assigned `nil` initially, and then doesn't ever change.

You might want to use `push` instead of `cons` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A list is nothing more than a linked list of cons cells, ending in a nil value.
For example (1 2 3) is equivalent to (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))

Your code by design is wrong, because what you are trying to construct being with nil, the empty list, and then you're trying to cons to it other elements. A corrected version of what you are trying to do would be

```
(defun r (list)
 (let ((o ()))
  (dolist (el list o)
   (setf o (cons el o))))
```

Comment: sorry, typo: "trying to construct beginning with nil"

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
(defun r(list)  
 (let ((o ()))
  (dolist (x list)
   (setf o (cons o x)))
  o))

 (r (list 1 2 3))
 (((NIL . 1) . 2) . 3)
```

If so, note the following:

- `dolist` assigns `x` from `list`: `(dolist (x list) ...`
- `o` must be set: `(setf o (...`
- `o` has to be "returned"

Comment: (dolist (x list o) ...) returns o.